# how to use Context in override

Tags: android, android-context

I am trying to grab UI change in my app (particularly soft keyboard shown or hidden), in order to this I have used custom listview in which I put

```
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)c
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (im.isActive()) {
        Log.d("Redraw Canvas", "Key board is active");
    } else {
        Log.d("Redraw Canvas", "Key board is not active");
    }

}
```

but it needs Context here, the question is how can I use the context here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`,  may be that will helpful

Comment: how come this answer is accepted when Raghav Sood answered the same long before this answer was posted.?

Answer (score 1):

`onDraw()` is a method in the View class, and each View holds a reference to its creator's Context. So simply use:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Every view has a `getContext()` method.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point the method exactly and the fact that it is available for all views. But your answer is the right one. @Raghav Sood

Comment: Yes it work pretty well, but the boolean always give me the true value, whatever the keyboard showen or hidden, why?

Comment: I know the reason why it returns true, because my edit text area always stay in focus so it.